# Message: Trying to get property of non-object mvc framework Codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I'm trying to echo/get the values in my table but I having a ***Message: Trying to get property of non-object***

Like this one

```
  <tr class="project-overview-customer">
                <td class="bold"><?php echo _l('dev_oqood_status'); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $developer->dev_oqood_status; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="project-overview-customer">
                <td class="bold"><?php echo _l('dev_contact'); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $developer->dev_contact; ?></td>
            </tr>
```

on my Model i have this

```
public function get_developer($id = '', $where = array())
    {
       $this->db->where($where);
       if (is_numeric($id)) {
        $this->db->where('project_id', $id);
            $developer = $this->db->get('tbldevdetails')->row();
            print_r($developer); die();
        }

            return $this->db->get('tbldevdetails')->result_array();


    }
```

Then When I do   `print_r($project); die();`

```
stdClass Object ( [dev_id] => 20 [project_id] => 49 [dev_devloper] => [dev_purchase_date] => 2018-02-27 [dev_handover_date] => 2018-02-27 [dev_oqood_status] => Mengaw [dev_contact] => 0 [dev_email] => Mengaw [dev_landline] => Mengaw [dev_mobile] => Mengaw )
```

Why I have this error? Anyone can guide me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$this->db->get('tbldevdetails')->row();` (which is what you are running `print_r()` on returns an object. Which you are correctly accessing with `<?php echo $developer->dev_oqood_status; ?>`. However...
You are not returning `$this->db->get('tbldevdetails')->row();` you are returning `$this->db->get('tbldevdetails')->result_array();`.. This is an Array which you would access like `$developer[0]['dev_oqood_status']`

So change your function `get_developer` to `return $developer;` instead.

Also know the difference between [Result Rows](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html#result-rows)  And [Result Arrays](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html#result-arrays) from the codeigniter framework

Comment: Hi, Thanks for explanation but first i try to call using $developer['dev_oqood_status']  but it gives me an undefined index and for and $developer[0] it gives me Array to string conversion error

Comment: @Mengaw Please may I see a `var_dump($developer)` called from your Model

Comment: here's the result object(stdClass)#58 (10) { ["dev_id"]=> string(2) "20" ["project_id"]=> string(2) "49" ["dev_devloper"]=> string(0) "" ["dev_purchase_date"]=> string(10) "2018-02-27" ["dev_handover_date"]=> string(10) "2018-02-27" ["dev_oqood_status"]=> string(7) "Mengaw" ["dev_contact"]=> string(1) "0" ["dev_email"]=> string(7) "Mengaw" ["dev_landline"]=> string(7) "Mengaw" ["dev_mobile"]=> string(7) "Mengaw" }

Comment: @Mengaw is that with returning with `->row()` or `->result_array()` because that looks like an object and not an array.

Comment: its with the `->row()`

Comment: @Mengaw then in your model you will call it with `$developer->dev_oqood_status`. The problem with before was that you were attempting to access an Array via Objects and now your issue is that you're trying to access Objects via an array haha

Comment: sorry I overlooked my code this is my vardump for `result_array()`  `array(1) { [0]=> array(10) { ["dev_id"]=> string(2) "20" ["project_id"]=> string(2) "49" ["dev_devloper"]=> string(0) "" ["dev_purchase_date"]=> string(10) "2018-02-27" ["dev_handover_date"]=> string(10) "2018-02-27" ["dev_oqood_status"]=> string(7) "Mengaw" ["dev_contact"]=> string(1) "0" ["dev_email"]=> string(7) "Mengaw" ["dev_landline"]=> string(7) "Mengaw" ["dev_mobile"]=> string(7) "Mengaw" } }`

Comment: @Mengaw In your model it should be  `$developer[0]['dev_oqood_status']` Looks like the return from `->result_array()` makes a multi dimension array. You'll have to access everything with `[0]`

Answer (score 0):

You are using `->result_array()` to get the `$developer`, so `$developer` is not an object, but is instead an array. You should return an object instead by using `->result()`.